# DFS replication and disk quotas on Windows 2008 R2 file servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dfs, file-server

How is disk quota treated in a DFS environment? Do quotas also get replicated to member servers? How do you setup quotas and file screening for this kind of environment? I'd like to know your experiences in setting this up.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this answers your question:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776144%28WS.10%29.aspx

Specifically from the link:

Using disk quotas on DFS link targets

DFS provides a simple way to create custom quotas on different volumes that appear to users as different folders on the same volume. If you are using DFS to provide multiple link targets, note that each of these link targets can reside on a volume with different quota settings. To keep the user experience consistent, use the same quota settings for each volume.

You may be looking for an answer directly for your environment, if you could provide more details this would be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: Essentially, what you're saying is -- I have to recreate the quotas on each member of the DFS replication group. Thanks for this. I thought this would have been simpler.

Comment: There should be a way to easily import/export.  I cant find the 2008 article but here is the 2003: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785375%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: actually here is the 2008 import/export at the bottom of this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163561.aspx